# online platform for flex application?

Tags: apache-flex, compiler-construction, flex4

Is there any platform/compiler for creating flex application online? Any version will work. I know some action script online compiler but not able to find any flex online compiler.

Answer (score 0):

There used to be one in the Flex 2 time frame; which Adobe created using the command line Flex compiler and ColdFusion.  You entered your code into an input box, and then on the backend it would compile it using the cfexecute command.

If you Google "Online Flex Compiler" a bunch of blog posts about it come up, but it looks like the actual app is no longer available.  Most likely because it was pretty useless.  Writing code in a browser is not very productive.

Comment: i did not find any online flex compiler.

Comment: Aye, that is what I said.  It appears to be gone.  But, there used to be one.  You could, in theory, create one using the command line compiler and a simple web form that submits code, compiles it, and punches out a SWF.

Answer (score 0):

Check out wonderfl: http://wonderfl.net/

Here's nifty example: http://wonderfl.net/c/y5Cx

Or are you looking for something different?